# Integration of SonarQube with ISML

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-plugin, isml

How to integrate ISML language plugin in sonarqube and analyze the code to get report?
I can see there is no plugin for ISML in sonarqube. How can I integrate the additional plugins  into sonarqube?
I'm using ISML linter for this currently, but that cannot be converted into dashboard in sonarqube. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't currently do that.

As you can fin in the [SonarQube Plugin Library Doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library) they don't have support for ISML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! , You mean to say that is impossible using sonarqube? or are there any other possible ways?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible as per today due is not supported.